# Show that $\tau$ is not a topology on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau=\{\Bbb{R},\emptyset,(q,\infty):q\in\Bbb{Q}\}$ Show that $\tau$ is not a topology on $\Bbb{R}$. 
 
The part

> $(q,\infty):q\in\Bbb{Q}$

confuses me. <strike>I think if we take infinite intersections of these sets we reach closed(or not open) sets, which makes $\tau$ incapable of being topology.</strike> 
 
<strike>Like intersections of { $(\frac{1}{n},\infty)$ }from n = 1 to $\infty$ we reach $[0,\infty)$ which is not open.</strike>

Comment: Topologies do not care about infinite intersections. They care about _finite_ intersections and arbitrary (_both_ finite _and_ infinite) unions.

Comment: that's not a problem, infinite intersection of open sets need not to be open (your example works in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as well) however arbitrary unions of open sets should be open, is that the case with this $\tau$?

Comment: Actually, if we intersect $(1/n,\infty)$, we end up with $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @diogenes: it would still be open. You are wanting $1-\frac1n$ to get the result you are aiming for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $q_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ be a decreasing sequence such that $q_i\to \sqrt{2}$ as $i\to\infty$ and consider
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i,\infty).$$

Comment: is it $[\sqrt{2},\infty)$?

Comment: @diogenes No it is $(\sqrt2,\infty)$ which is not an element of $\tau$ (in contrast with every $(q_i,\infty)$)

Answer (score 3):

Finite intersections belong to $\tau$. But what about
$$\bigcup_{\substack{q^2> 2\\q>0}}(q,\infty)?$$

Comment: @diogenes, he explains why it is indeed the real line.

Comment: When this answer was written, the union was over the $q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q>\sqrt2$. I don't know why the author changed it.

Comment: @Clayton I fixed it. Easier than downvoting and wait for correction.

Comment: @egreg: yep. I had already upvoted :) I like the simplicity of $q>\sqrt2$ more than defining a sequence as the other answer suggests, that is the only reason I know what the author originally had written.

Comment: Guys, are you trying to make me understand "rational numbers converge to irrational numbers and my $\tau$ has no interval starting with an irrational number"?

Comment: More precisely $\bigcup_{q\in A}(q,\infty)=(\sqrt2,\infty)\notin\tau$ where $A=\{r\in\mathbb Q\mid r>\sqrt2\}$